# Firebase Functions packages are not installing during deployment

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

Local build and emulation work without error (my code notwithstanding). On deployment, Firebase Hosting complains that the package and package-lock are not in sync.

```
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app-compat@0.2.13 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app@0.9.13 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.4 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: tslib@2.6.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.4 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: idb@7.1.1 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: tslib@2.6.0 from lock file
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-06-30T16_26_12_626Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
```

Locally using `npm i`/`ci` does not sync the 2 files. A coworker pushed their -lock file and everything is great until I do `npm i`/`ci` which then removes the entries from the -lock file.

Additionally, using `find` reveals that the path to the log file (the last line) does not exist.

Our package files are in sync, node 16.16.0, npm 8.11.0, `npm install -g npm` does not help.

What is a potential cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a mismatch between your `package-lock.json` file and your `package.json` file. When the dependencies listed in `package.json` are not accurately represented in the lock file, this can happen.

Make sure the same version of npm is used to create and manage both files. You can try deleting `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and then re-running `npm init` and `npm install` to create them from scratch.

As an alternative, you can try running `npm cache clean --force` before attempting to execute `npm install` once more.

It would also be helpful to share further information or snippets from your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files if none of these fixes solves the problem.